# Problem with importing softmax from scipy and using it once imported from sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, conda, softmax

I have installed scipy using conda.

When I try to import softmax from scipy I get an error:

```
from scipy.special import softmax
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-35eed14e1f88> in <module>
----> 1 from scipy.special import softmax

ImportError: cannot import name 'softmax' from 'scipy.special' (C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py)
```

On the other hand I can import softmax from sklearn but then I get an exception when I try to put it in use:

```
from sklearn.utils.extmath import softmax
X = np.array([[2, 3], [4,5]])
softmax(X)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-781ae2561cff> in <module>
      1 X = np.array([[2, 3], [4,5]])
----> 2 softmax(X)

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py in softmax(X, copy)
    597     max_prob = np.max(X, axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
    598     X -= max_prob
--> 599     np.exp(X, X)
    600     sum_prob = np.sum(X, axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
    601     X /= sum_prob

TypeError: ufunc 'exp' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'l') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''
```

Comment: What is the SciPy version? `scipy.special.softmax` wasn't added until v1.2.0.

Comment: There is no need to add `Your advice will be appreciated` to the footer of all of your questions. You've probably had ~100 removed by now. Remember that the editors that try to keep this place tidy are volunteers. We may be foolish for taking on the task, but we believe in this community, for all its many faults. We would rather not have to clean up after users who add redundant and conversational material wilfully.

Comment: The SciPy version is the latest.  I just updated using pip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of your question is probably answered by the comment and boils down to the version of SciPy you're using simply being one that doesn't include `softmax`. For the second part, the error message suggests that it's failing to convert a double to a long; you can get around this by simply using only doubles in your input:

```py
In [13]: softmax(X.astype(np.double))                                                                    
Out[13]: 
array([[0.26894142, 0.73105858],
       [0.26894142, 0.73105858]])
```

That `softmax` does not work with integers is also apparent from [the documentation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b5cf50c3f7fcc723a9df205d898964b84a3f1620/sklearn/utils/extmath.py#L596) and is [by design](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11226):

> ### Parameters
>
> X : array-like of *floats*, shape (M, N)
>      Argument to the logistic function

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by upgrading scikit-learn and scipy to the newest version:

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn scipy
```